# Using srcset for background image in ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, srcset

I am using ACF to allow a client to upload images that will be used as a full-screen background on the home page. The image will differ depending on the day of the week. I have created custom image sizes for the background images and I have a function that will query the server for the day of the week and find the corresponding image. I am having trouble getting the function to return the correct image size.

Here is my function:

```
function my_custom_background () { 

$today = date('l');
$image = get_field (strtolower($today));
$size = 'auto'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
$backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image ( $image, $size );


?><style>body.page-id-5 {background-image: url( '<?php echo $backgroundImg; ?>'); }</style><?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_background');
```

And here is what is rendered:

```
background-image: url( '<img width="1920" height="1258" src="http://dev.whydidibother.com/klwdp/jumpstart-full-screen-image-daily-change-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/10/amazing-beautiful-breathtaking-clouds.jpg" class="attachment-auto size-auto" alt="" srcset="http://dev.whydidibother.com/klwdp/jumpstart-full-screen-image-daily-change-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/10/amazing-beautiful-breathtaking-clouds.jpg 1920w, http://dev.whydidibother.com/klwdp/jumpstart-full-screen-image-daily-change-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/10/amazing-beautiful-breathtaking-clouds-300x197.jpg 300w, http://dev.whydidibother.com/klwdp/jumpstart-full-screen-image-daily-change-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/10/amazing-beautiful-breathtaking-clouds-768x503.jpg 768w, http://dev.whydidibother.com/klwdp/jumpstart-full-screen-image-daily-change-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/10/amazing-beautiful-breathtaking-clouds-1024x671.jpg 1024w, http://dev.whydidibother.com/klwdp/jumpstart-full-screen-image-daily-change-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/10/amazing-beautiful-breathtaking-clouds-1200x786.jpg 1200w, http://dev.whydidibother.com/klwdp/jumpstart-full-screen-image-daily-change-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/10/amazing-beautiful-breathtaking-clouds-800x524.jpg 800w, http://dev.whydidibother.com/klwdp/jumpstart-full-screen-image-daily-change-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/10/amazing-beautiful-breathtaking-clouds-500x328.jpg 500w" sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" />');
```

Grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Wordpress reference for `wp_get_attachment_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/), you'll see that this function returns an html element. I would recommend to set your ACF image fields to return the image object (which actually returns an array) and then get the proper size as follows:

```
$image = get_field(strtolower($today));
echo $image['sizes']['large']; // thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom
```

See also the ACF documentation for [image field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) (section "Customized display (arrray)").